# How to say "even" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

English version:

> *As he is very lazy, he doesn't even wash  his hands before eating.*

Japanese version (but incomplete):

彼は、非常に怠惰なので、食べる前に、手を洗っていない。

How do we add "even" in Japanese to my translation above?

Comment: I wonder how 「〜手を洗いもしない。」 would work. By the way, I don't think commas are used quite that frequently. I'm not a native speaker, but I might say 「彼はすごく怠惰で、食事の前に手を洗うこともしない」 or 「彼はすごく怠惰で、食事の前にも手を洗わない。」

Comment: I would probably use さえ or すら in this case, i.e. 手すら洗っていない.

Comment: The word 「怠惰」 is way too big for this simple context.  It really does not belong in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say your English version in various ways in Japanese, e.g.

> 彼はとても[物臭]{ものぐさ}なので、[食前]{しょくぜん}に手も洗わない。
>
> 彼は非常に[怠]{なま}け者なので、食べる前に手を洗うことすらしない。
>
> 彼はとても[生臭]{なまぐさ}で、手も洗わないで食事をする。
>
> 彼は全くルーズな男（[面倒臭]{めんどうくさ}がり屋）だから、食事の前に手も洗わない。

“非常に怠惰” sounds somewhat bookish to me. It’s a big word as @l’electeur pointed out, and I wouldn’t use ‘怠惰’ in daily conversation.

Comment: Couldn't you use からして to express this too?

Comment: “からして” means an old expression of ’’because” and “as,” like “彼は怠惰であるからして食前に手も洗わない,” which mean “Because he is lazy, he doesn’t even wash his hands before eating.” It may match the stiff and bookish expression, “怠惰.”

Answer (score 5):

I would use 「も」 as in:

> 彼はとてもめんどくさがり屋(なの)で、食事の前に/食べる前に手**も**洗わない。

Comment: 「めんどくさがり[屋]{や}」は「めんどくさがり」でもいいと思います。「[面倒]{めんどう}くさがり」「面倒くさがり屋」と書いてもいいと思います。

Comment: めんどくさがり屋というよりも、汚がり屋ですね。

Comment: ^ 「[汚]{きたな}がり屋」って・・・？「汚がる人」「汚がって嫌がる人」なら「きれい好き」のことじゃない？

Comment: 面倒くさがり屋 is a quite common word, but I don't hear the word, 汚がり屋, albeit you can suffix 屋 to anything you'd like to.