# Grammar question about [sentence]のに

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-も, particle-か

I was asked by my teacher to read a kid friendly manga, something easy to start with.

I am not having issue with the vocabulary and I understand the general gist of a sentence but I am having issue with "why" is the sentence constructed that way.

> そういえばほかのボールがどこにあるかもわからないのにどうやって探すんだ？

So what I get from this is :

> Come to think of it how are we going to find the place, that I don't
>   know, where the ball is.

But I am a bit confused grammar-wise with two things :

> ある**かも**

and

> わからない**のに**

These are my best guesses :

ある**かも** -> か　is to show that the character is asking where is the place of the ball

も is used here to say the character doesn't know **anything** about it

わからないのに -> に say that the previous part of the sentence is **where** they need to look

の I really have no idea why a no would be here

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence can be roughly divided into three parts:

> そういえば、｛ほかのボールがどこにあるか｝もわからないのに、どうやって探すんだ？

- そういえば is a common set phrase, "come to think of it", "as I recall."
- ほかのボールがどこにあるか forms an [embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/5010). "where the other balls are".
- ～が分かる is "to know/understand ～".
- The following も replaces が, and adds the nuance of "(not) even". See: [The meaning of 「尋ねられもしないこと」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34431/5010) and [How to say "even" in Japanese?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32201/5010)
- のに is a common conjunction that means "although", "despite the fact that ～". See examples [here](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=noni).

> Come to think of it, how can we find (it) when we don't even know where the other balls are?

I don't know what exactly they are searching for from this context. Maybe they are searching for something which is related to 'the other balls'.

Comment: So I wasn't far off but I'm happy to have the complete explanation and link to answers. Thank you